# How to select date range from CalendarView in android?

Tags: android, calendar

I need to select more than once date from a CalenderView of android. Can any one help me to do the same.

Example!
Let's look attached image. If we consider the calender in image as CalenderView of android I need to select all date raging from 16th to 20th.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the `CalendarView` only supports selecting single dates.

I would suggest calling it twice to get the start and end dates (for the end date, you could call [`setMinDate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html#setMinDate%28long%29) beforehand to make sure it's greater than the start date).

Comment: Thanks for your reply...but I also need to show it like it is shown in image. Selected date should be looks like these many dates are selected.

Comment: @SanketPatel : have you found any libraries for doing as showed above? can you share with me

Comment: @NageswaraRao.CH try here https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview